# Magento tax don't get count on Imported products, working on manually inserted products

Tags: magento, syntax

I have imported approx 100 products from Magento admin, it's working fine and displaying well with images. But I have one strange issue, I am not able to count Tax in the cart for these products.

The strange thing is, if I insert any products manually from admin Manage Product section, Tax get count for this products with out any issue, but not for the products which are imported.

I have created Tax rule that count's 13% tax for the Canada only, for rest of the world  it's with out any tax

Is any body have any solution for this issue?

One more thing I would like to say, my site was multy store and I have removed many store few days ago, but no deleted the store wrohit

Thanks & Regards
Rohit Avasthi

Answer (score 0):

Given that it works with other products, I assume you have the tax configured correctly and the issue occurs only based on the particular products.

I would go and check **Tax Class** property in the **Prices** tab inside admin product view. In order to calculate tax, there should be an appropriate tax class set (the same tax class that you have used in your tax rule). When creating the product in admin, this is a required field, while during import it may be left not validated and thus imported as "not set"